# Counting index entries

Tags: indexing, counters

Is there a way to count the number of entries in an `.idx` file? Currently I'm using the following to accomplish the job but I'm wondering if there is an all TeX/LaTeX way to accomplish the same thing. Were there then I wouldn't have to fit a run of 'Count' into the build process. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Count.pl -- generate index count info for tex
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

our $VERSION = '0.04';

UpdateLines('names.tex',NLines($ARGV[0] . '.idx'));
UpdateLines('places.tex',NLines('places.idx'));

sub NLines {
    my $filename = shift;
    my @f;
    my $fh;

    open($fh, '<', $filename);
    @f = <$fh>;
    return scalar @f;
}

sub UpdateLines {
    my $filename = shift;
    my $lines = shift;
    my $fh;

    open($fh, '>', $filename);
    print $fh "There are $lines entries in this index.\n";
}
```

It occurs to me as I write this that since I use a collection of macros to index the various forms of names and places that I could add the necessary to increment the obvious counters `inline` so to speak. If anyone else has a better idea, jump on board. If not and if I manage to cobble something together then I'll post it as an answer in case someone else has this `counting compulsion`. OCD much?

Comment: You could redefine `\index` to add to a CSV the list of enteres that are indexed (if not already in the list), and then `\AtEndDocument` count the number of elements in this CSV.

Comment: If all you want is the line count then (on *nix) `wc -l` is easier than the perl script (except that you've already written the perl script).

Comment: What's the aim? Do you use `xindy` or `makeindex`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Each index has a line that states `There are n entries in this index.` The Perl script was how I counted them simply by counting lines in the `.idx` file created by `makeindex`.

Comment: @EthanBolker On Windows too if you have the full GNU toolset :) The Perl script allows formatting and un-anticipated changes. Toss up as to which would be easier just `n` or `There are...`

Comment: @PeterGrill Excellent point---but complicated by the need for multiple counts I think.

Comment: sorry to be a nit-picker (it's my curse in life) -- how should a *see* or *see also* entry be counted?  (as well as the simple difference that results from multiple references to the same entry text; see my comment to @egreg's answer.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ah! You of course have `Editor's Disease`! As do I :) The answer is that precision is not a requirement here. Since this is a family history, the numbers are more of a guide than anything else. At the moment, the naive approach just counts lines in the `.idx` files. My new approach counts each instance of indexing. I'll have to give this some thought as to what would be best. Luckily the audience is un-critical :)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `\item` command to increment a counter and then the `\endtheindex` command to show the counter value (and to reset the counter to zero for the next index):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=names,title=Index of Names]
\makeindex[name=places,title=Index of Places]

\makeatletter
% in the index, \item is \@idxitem
\appto{\@idxitem}{\stepcounter{itemcount}}
% Show the counter's value at the end and reset the counter
\appto{\endtheindex}{%
  \noindent\fbox{This index had \theitemcount~items}\par
  \setcounter{itemcount}{0}}

\newcounter{itemcount}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A}
\index[names]{Euclid}
\index[places]{Alexandria}

\index[names]{Archimedes}
\index[places]{Syracuse}

\index[names]{Euler}
\index[places]{Basel}
\index[places]{Berlin}
\index[places]{St. Peterburg}

\index[names]{Newton}
\index[places]{Cambridge}


\backmatter

\printindex[names]
\printindex[places]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice! Some very useful internals here :) More Virtual Cake(TM) in the offing here :)

Comment: @egreg -- this is nice and straightforward, but what if (as expressed in the original question) the number of entries should be the number of entries in the `.idx` file?  what if one "final" entry has multiple page numbers?  and what is actually wanted if an entry happens to be indexed twice on a single page, in which case the `.idx` file would have two entries, but the `.ind` file will have only one?

Comment: @barbarabeeton In that case I would count the lines in the `.idx` file, rather than patching the `\index` command, probably with a Perl (or the preferred language) script. A TeX-only solution could be devised, but it would be rather slow.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The original (1st edition) index had 5824 entries for names and was neither accurate nor complete. I'm significantly OCD when it comes to this such that I'll probably spend quite a bit of time figuring out what would be best.

Comment: @egreg I have similar question as @barbara beeton : How to do the counting if there is only a subentry to the index e.g. `\index[names]{Euler!childhood}` so it would count `childhood` but not `Euler` if I don't have explicitly `\index[names]{Euler}`?

Comment: @LukasCB Change accordingly also `\subitem`

Comment: I am surely doing it wrong: `\appto{\@idxsubitem}{\stepcounter{subitemcount}}` is not working, how do I change it accordingly?

Comment: @LukasCB Actually I was too fast; the definition of `\subitem` in LaTeX is `\@idxitem\hspace*{20\p@}`, so the subitems are already accounted for with the above code. If you want a separate count for the subitems, then it's a different thing.

Comment: ok, I see. But if I understand it the number is misleading because it adds the `\item` to the `\subitem` . example `\index[places]{Rome!Forum!Temple of Caesar}` adds the number 3 to the counter? But it is only add 1 to the counter.

Comment: Now I get it - it is counting the places and not the number of entries of the (sub)places. So it is not as easy as it seems to get the number of the (actual) (sub)entries?

Comment: @LukasCB Not in comments, at least

Answer (score 3):

An atempt to answer the original question. 
The number of entries in the .idx file is counted via `\input` command:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\def\CountIndexOccurrences#1{%
\expandafter\newcount\csname #1\endcsname%
\expandafter\newcount\csname #1\endcsname%
\def\indexentry##1##2{\expandafter\advance\csname #1\endcsname 1}%
\IfFileExists{#1.idx}{\input{#1.idx}}{}%
}
\CountIndexOccurrences{names}
\CountIndexOccurrences{places}
\def\TotalBox#1{%
\fbox{There are \expandafter\the\csname #1\endcsname\ occurrences 
of items from this index}\par}
\makeindex[name=names,title=Index of Names]%
\makeindex[name=places,title=Index of Places]%
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A}
Euclid\index[names]{Euclid}
(Alexandria\index[places]{Alexandria})

Archimedes\index[names]{Archimedes}
(Syracuse\index[places]{Syracuse})

Newton\index[names]{Newton}
(Cambridge\index[places]{Cambridge})

\newpage
Newton\index[names]{Newton}
(Cambridge\index[places]{Cambridge})

Euler\index[names]{Euler}
(Basel\index[places]{Basel},
Berlin\index[places]{Berlin},
St. Peterburg\index[places]{St.~Peterburg})

Newton\index[names]{Newton}
(Cambridge\index[places]{Cambridge})

Euclid\index[names]{Euclid}
(Alexandria\index[places]{Alexandria})

\backmatter

\printindex[names]
\TotalBox{names}
\printindex[places]
\TotalBox{places}
\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]
[image: Index of Names]
[image: Index of Places]

Content of the `names.idx`, 7 entries:

```
\indexentry{Euclid}{1}
\indexentry{Archimedes}{1}
\indexentry{Newton}{1}
\indexentry{Newton}{2}
\indexentry{Euler}{2}
\indexentry{Newton}{2}
\indexentry{Euclid}{2}
```

Content of the `places.idx`, 9 entries:

```
\indexentry{Alexandria}{1}
\indexentry{Syracuse}{1}
\indexentry{Cambridge}{1}
\indexentry{Cambridge}{2}
\indexentry{Basel}{2}
\indexentry{Berlin}{2}
\indexentry{St.~Peterburg}{2}
\indexentry{Cambridge}{2}
\indexentry{Alexandria}{2}
```

Comment: Is there an off by one error here or am I unable to count? Bear in mind that inability to count may be true regardless :)

Comment: Why don't you put the code now in `\CountIndexOccurrences` inside `\TotalBox`? You won't even need a new counter, just use a temporary one such as `\count255`. Inputting the `.idx` file in the preamble or after `\printindex` takes the same time and, after `\printindex` the file will be there and closed, because `imakeidx` closes the `.idx` file in order to run MakeIndex.

Comment: @hsmyers It's neither :) It's just different things were counted. It counts the number of \idexenrty in idx files, as was originally requested (see content of the names.idx and places.idx just added for convenience). A few entries were added to the MWE in order to address some of remarks (some of the entries on the same page).

Comment: @egreg: There's more than one way to skin a cat. Besides, when files are scanned in the preamble, the numbers can be used, say, in the Introduction.

Comment: @g.kov You could also write the result in the `.aux` file. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: This would be an extra file writing operation.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the body of the question, here is the solution I came up with some 8 hours ago (would have posted then excepting my link to `tex.stackexchange.com` was down. That aside, here is my counter neutral code:

```
%%
%% Indexing Macros
%%
\newcounter{Names}
\newcounter{Places}
\newcommand{\incNames}{\addtocounter{Names}{1}}
\newcommand{\incPlaces}{\addtocounter{Places}{1}}
\newcommand\IA[3]{\incNames #1\index{#2!#3}}
\newcommand\IAA[3]{\incNames #1\index{#2 (#3)}}
\newcommand\IM[4]{\incNames #1\index{#2!#3, (#4.)}}
\newcommand\IS[1]{\incNames #1\index{#1 \ding{45}}}
\newcommand\PI[1]{\incPlaces #1\index[places]{#1 \ding{45}}}
\newcommand\PIA[2]{\incPlaces #1\index[places]{#1, (\SCA{#2})}}
\newcommand\PIAA[3]{\incPlaces #1\index[places]{#2, (\SCA{#3})}}
\newcommand\PO[3]{\incPlaces #1\index[places]{#1, (\SCA{#2})|{\emph{\small #3}}}}
\newcommand\SCA[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
```

Starting at `\IA`, are the modified originals. This so blindingly obvious now that it is in place that it makes me question my problem solving abilities :( Clearly I need more practice in answers---questions are easy, need to get back to answers! As an aside, it is fun to see that this modification ups the `self-documentation` factor!